# Pass multiple args to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, argument-passing

I want to pass multiple values to a function in uploadify.

The way you call a function is like this

```
$("#id").uploadify("upload", fileId);
```

here fileId is id of only one file to be uploaded.

I have a scenario where i itertate over a table to get file ids to upload then i want to pass those ids to this function call. How can i do that.

and here is currently what i am doing, which obviously isn't working.

```
var imagesToUpload = [];
$.each(data.validationResult, function (index, obj) {
var imageToUpload = GetFileToUpload(obj.ImageName);
   if(imageToUpload){
      imagesToUpload[imageToUpload] = imageToUpload;
   }
});
$("#id").uploadify("upload", imagesToUpload);// this is not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass arguments to a function as an array.

```
$('#id').uploadify.apply(null, ['upload'].concat(imagesToUpload));
```

This assumes that `imagesToUpload` is an Array of the arguments you want to pass.